API level android studio Java teniendo todos los SDKs
Tengo un problema con android studio, y es que al realizar un proyecto simple me percate de que di el parametro inicial de Android 13 como minimo, y descubri que puedo bajar el nivel de API meidnate el codigo en el tajetSDK y CompileSKD al hacerlo me arroja error teniendo descargados los SDKS en tools sdk manager, alguna solucion o debo crear el codigo desde cero?



Usa minSdkVersion en lugar de minSdk y targetSdkVersion en lugar de targetSdk, esto debe ser el problema por el cuál no detecta correctamente tu configuración, realiza el cambio:
android {
    namespace 'com.example.ihealth4u'
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.example.ihealth4u"

        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

}


Ya he hecho la modificacion y me sigue dando el error de "Google Play requieres that apps target API Level 33 or higher"

Cambia a targetSdkVersion 33, seguramente agregaste una dependencia que necesita esta versión

estas son mis dependencias mira

implementation libs.appcompat
implementation libs.material
implementation libs.activity
implementation libs.constraintlayout
implementation libs.firebase.auth
testImplementation libs.junit
androidTestImplementation libs.ext.junit
androidTestImplementation libs.espresso.core
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1"))
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")

Cambia a  compileSdkVersion 33 y prueba nuevamente! @FernandoCasanova

si logre solucionarlo muchisimas gracias

@FernandoCasanova si esta respuesta te sirvió favor de marcarla como solución , revisa [tour]
